Raspberry pi ubuntu apt upgrade not working and stuck at [Waiting for headers]
I am trying to update my raspberry pi (running ubuntu server 64-bit), But cant seem to run sudo apt upgrade. this is what usually happens:
$ sudo apt update
# it completes really fast

$ sudo apt upgrade
Ign 1: https://ports.ubuntu.com/.....
# or gets a has error
0% [Waiting for headers]

I'm not sure what is wrong, I am connected to ethernet (but have tried both), and raspberry pi OS updates/upgrades fine.

I'd suggest reading all output of commands, eg. sudo apt update should provide lines of data, are those lines without errors, warnings or missing lines?   What release are you using?  Read the whole line of your upgrade line as does that detail provide clues (we're limited to what you provide us, and "....."  is not expected on that line)

According to https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ the https://ports.ubuntu.com/ site is currently down for everyone.

sources.list is deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
